# Ajax request fails while a website can make the same request successfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[This website](https://www.museodelprado.es/en/the-collection/art-works) dynamically loads in content when the user scrolls further down. When scrolling down, the website sends a AJAX request (as can be seen in the dev tools > network tab), which returns JSON data.

When I manually make the request, either by [browsing to](https://resultados4.museodelprado.es/CargadorResultados/CargarResultados) or by my own request :

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://resultados4.museodelprado.es/CargadorResultados/CargarResultados",
        success: function(response) {
            data_holder = response;
        }
    });
```

it returns a runtime error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

How can I send the AJAX request to return the JSON data, instead of the runtime error?

## Edit

[This image shows the devtools > network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UakPf.png)

Comment: What about 14 form params that POST request requires?

Comment: It's a post request but not with an empty body

Comment: @Satpal Quite certain. I've added the view from the devtool output.

Comment: You need to set POST request params (pUsarMasterParaLectura, pProyectoID, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request does not work because the ajax call needs parameters, the code would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://resultados4.museodelprado.es/CargadorResultados/CargarResultados",
    data: {
        cont: 0,
        pAdministradorVeTodasPersonas: false,
        pEsUsuarioInvitado: true,
        pFiltroContexto: "",
        pGrafo: "7317a29a-d846-4c54-9034-6a114c3658fe",
        pIdentidadID: "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF",
        pLanguageCode: "en",
        pNumeroParteResultados: 1,
        pParametros: "|pagina=2",
        pParametros_adiccionales: "PestanyaActualID=c89fbb0c-a52c-4700-9220-79f4964d3949|rdf:type=pmartwork|orden=asc|ordenarPor=pm:relevance,ecidoc:p62_E52_p79_has_time-span_beginning,ecidoc:p62_E52_p80_has_time-span_end,gnoss:hasfechapublicacion",
        pPrimeraCarga: false,
        pProyectoID: "7317a29a-d846-4c54-9034-6a114c3658fe",
        pTipoBusqueda: 0,
        pUsarMasterParaLectura: false
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

the result is a JSON with 2 parameters: `Key` and `Value` like

```
<div id="numResultadosRemover"> <strong>3421</strong> results </div>
<div class="mostrable miniaturas">
  <figure>
    <div class="imgwrap">
      <a href="https://www.museodelprado.es/en/the-collection/art-work/the-creation-of-adam-the-hermitage-of-the-vera/52e8a064-dfad-43db-a9f9-939eeba21869"> <img src="https://content3.cdnprado.net/imagenes/Documentos/imgsem/52/52e8/52e8a064-dfad-43db-a9f9-939eeba21869/b1ee2320-41b9-4992-bdb2-88ad76fcb5c6_268.jpg" alt=""> </a> <a href="https://www.museodelprado.es/en/cmspagina?ComponentName=operativaLogin&amp;titulo=The+Creation+of+Adam.+The+Hermitage+of+the+Vera+Cruz+de+Maderuelo&amp;imagen=https%3a%2f%2fcontent3.cdnprado.net%2fimagenes%2fDocumentos%2fimgsem%2f52%2f52e8%2f52e8a064-dfad-43db-a9f9-939eeba21869%2fb1ee2320-41b9-4992-bdb2-88ad76fcb5c6_268.jpg&amp;idobra=52e8a064-dfad-43db-a9f9-939eeba21869" class="mi-prado modal-popup" href="#">Add to My Prado</a> </div>
    <figcaption class="presentacion-mosaico">
      <dl> <dt class="trunca-texto"><a href="https://www.museodelprado.es/en/the-collection/art-work/the-creation-of-adam-the-hermitage-of-the-vera/52e8a064-dfad-43db-a9f9-939eeba21869">The Creation of Adam. The Hermitage of the Vera Cruz de Maderuelo</a></dt>
        <dd class="trunca-texto soporte">Fresco painting on mural transferred to canvas. XII century</dd>
        <dd class="trunca-texto autor"><a href="https://www.museodelprado.es/en/the-collection/art-works?cidoc:p14_carried_out_by@@@pm:author@@@ecidoc:p131_E82_p102_has_title=anonymous@en">Anonymous</a>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </figcaption>
    <figcaption class="presentacion-listado">
      <dl> <dt><a href="https://www.museodelprado.es/en/the-collection/art-work/the-creation-of-adam-the-hermitage-of-the-vera/52e8a064-dfad-43db-a9f9-939eeba21869">The Creation of Adam. The Hermitage of the Vera Cruz de Maderuelo</a></dt>
        <dd class="soporte">Fresco painting on mural transferred to canvas. XII century</dd>
        <dd class="autor"><a href="https://www.museodelprado.es/en/the-collection/art-works?cidoc:p14_carried_out_by@@@pm:author@@@ecidoc:p131_E82_p102_has_title=anonymous@en">Anonymous</a>
        </dd>
        <p> The mural paintings from the Hermitage of the Vera Cruz de Maderuelo were transferred to canvas in 1947 and reconstructed at the Prado Museum in a layout as faithful to the original as possible. The w <span class="mas-info">[<span><a href="https://www.museodelprado.es/en/the-collection/art-work/the-creation-of-adam-the-hermitage-of-the-vera/52e8a064-dfad-43db-a9f9-939eeba21869">+</a></span>]</span>
        </p>
      </dl>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```